# My CSS animation isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to make an animation and I went searching for some codes. On "codepen.io" it worked but when I aplly it to my code, the animation doesn't work. Basically I want to click on a little DeLorean image and the car just moves horizontally to the right and then, with a script, I can delay the hyperlink until it reaches the side of the page. I also used a script to change the image on hover so I don't know if anything is clashing. The scripts of the delay and the hover option are working but I can't make the other one to work. Can somebody help me?

I used these codes:

```js
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#delorean").on({
   mouseenter: function(){
    $(this).attr('src','delorean-hover.jpg');
  },
  mouseleave: function(){
    $(this).attr('src','delorean.jpg');
  }
  });

});
</script>

<script>
$('.box').click(function() {
  $('.transform').toggleClass('transform-active');
});
</script>

<script>
function delay (URL) {
    setTimeout( function() { window.location = URL }, 600 );
}
</script>
```

```css
.nav2 {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 300px;
 display: inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 z-index: 1;
}

.box {
 height:50px;
 float:left;
}

.transform {
 -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
 -o-transition: all 2s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 2s ease;
 transition: all 2s ease;
 margin-top: 35vh;
 margin-left:11vw;
}

.transform-active {
 margin-top: 35vh;
 margin-left:110vw;
}
```

```html
 <div class="nav2"><a href="javascript:delay('URL')"><img src="delorean.jpg" class="box transform" id="delorean"></a>
  </div>
```

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never put the `script` tags above the `body`, unless you're using someone else's script and they specifically tell you to.

You're supposed to put them at the bottom of the `body`. This is because, when `script` tags are parsed by the browser *before* the `body`, none of the scripts recognize any of the elements in the body yet, and so in your case they can't actually find the DeLorean to be able to register clicks on it! It hasn't been loaded yet.

Move your `script` tags to the bottom of the `body` and it should work.

Comment: THANKS A LOT! It worked properly! I could finally understand why it wasn't working! God bless you for being so kind and considerate! I cannot thank you enough!